SimpleLightBox trigger open with button jQuery
I have looked at all examples, including those at https://simplelightbox.com/ but I seem to be stuck and wondering if something else isn't going on that I am missing.
I am intializing a simpleLightbox using the following code directly from the examples.
    var gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox(); 

It works no problem when I click on the gallery a.link.
I am trying to trigger this gallery to open from a stand alone button that says "View Gallery" It has a class called .view-gallery. It has the following on click associated with it.
    $(document).on('click', '.view-gallery', function (event) {
        gallery.open();
    })

Again, that is coming directly from the examples at simplelightbox.
I know the click event is triggered as I can console.log some junk in there and it returns. On click I get thrown the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: gallery.open is not a function
<anonymous> https://*/wp-content/themes/wilhelm/js/main.js?ver=1719958181:84
jQuery 10
<anonymous> https://*/wp-content/themes/wilhelm/inc/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=6.5.5:6
<anonymous> https://*/wp-content/themes/wilhelm/inc/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=6.5.5:6
<anonymous> https://*/wp-content/themes/wilhelm/inc/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=6.5.5:6 

From documentation : open -- Opens the lightbox with an given Element
Why is this so hard?

gallery itself does not appear to exist at that point. Likely an issue with variable scope.

I was using an older version that did not have open function defined. I loaded the latest from GitHub and it worked.
